# How to get rid of response headings in Google Sheets?

Tags: sql, arrays, google-sheets-formula, offset, google-query-language

I read an API with Google Sheets and want to get results similarly to this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
| Input | Formula           | Result column   |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 11    | =MyApiFormula(A2) | responseValue11 |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
| 22    | =MyApiFormula(A3) | responseValue22 |
+-------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

But the API is a bit strange and puts always a header row into response. With it, the response of the first formula looks like:

```
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
| Input | Formula           | Result column     |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
| 11    | =MyApiFormula(A2) | responseHeading11 |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|       |                   | responseValue11   |
+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

and the second formula (`=MyApiFormula(A3)`) doesn't work at all - sure, because it is forced to write into cells with already existing data.

I guess, this heading row can be avoided with a `=QUERY` formula with `INDEX` and an `offset` `-1` - but I fail with correct syntax.

Could somoebody point me to the correct writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QUERY syntax would be:

```
=QUERY(...; "offset 1"; 0)
```

substitute dots for your formula